# Arabic text not displaying in datatable

Tags: php, codeigniter, text, datatable, arabic

I have Arabic text in database table. I need to fetch it and display in datatable. But results blank. I can insert Arabic text. Please help me. Thanks in advance.
My controller function is given below.file_title contain Arabic text.

```
$this->datatables->select('pfile_print_media_id,clients.client_id,full_name,publication_name,page,pfile_date,file_title,image,size,total_cost,clients.currency,market_name')
                        ->from('pfile_print_media');
                $this->datatables->add_column('Title','$1','get_print_pfile(pfile_print_media_id,file_title)');
        }echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

here is my view page

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/file/ajax_pfile',
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayStart ":20,
            "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": "<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/ajax-loader_dark.gif'>"
    },  
    "fnInitComplete": function() {
            //oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
     },
            'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
        {
          $.ajax
          ({
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type'    : 'POST',
            'url'     : sSource,
            'data'    : aoData,
            'success' : fnCallback
          });  

                }

} );
```

Comment: maybe its a charset problem

Comment: Could you please tell how can I solve charset problem?

Comment: yes. In your views header set the proper charset: <meta charset="UTF-8">

Also do this in the config: $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

And also with the database: $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

Also, make sure that your database has the same charset that you're specifying. (Im using UTF8 to make the example, choose the charset you need)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Everything is configured as you said. But the result is blank.

Comment: could you show how are you doing that?

Comment: sorry. Ive never used that extension